Multiplying two bivariate polynomials using FFT for univariate polynomials multiplication
Let $$f(x,y)=\sum_{0\le i\le n , 0 \le j \le d}a_{i,j}x^iy^j$$ $$g(x,y)=\sum_{0\le i\le n , 0 \le j \le d}b_{i,j}x^iy^j$$
We want to multiply $f g$.
I did the following: $$f(x,x^{2n+1})=\sum_{0\le i\le n , 0 \le j \le d}a_{i,j}x^ix^{j(2n+1)}$$
Thus we can define $$F(z)=\sum_{0\le i\le n , 0 \le j \le d}a_{i,j}z^{i+j(2n+1)}$$ $$G(z)=\sum_{0\le i\le n , 0 \le j \le d}b_{i,j}z^{i+j(2n+1)}$$
So obviously we can calculate the product $F G$ in $O(nd \log(nd))$ using FFT for univariate polynomial multiplication.
The only part I miss in my proof is how to infer $(f g)(x,y)$ from $F G$.

Thank you for the fix!  I recommend you use standard notation for multiplication, rather than inventing new notation.  What is your question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.

@D.W. Got it, thanks! If anyone can help I will appreciate it
